# Doing fulltext search meta tags in php?

Tags: php, search, tags, full-text-search, meta

So I have my meta tags(title,description) set up where they switch based on the page that I am on. Works great.

Now I also have a global fulltext search setup. It searches through a table in db and returns the results. It works as well.

The issue I have is the fact that that every time I do a search, it doesn't index the title/search terms in the meta tags.  So I am wondering how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What search engine are you using? If it's homebrew, look at its code to see if it's stripping out meta tags. If it's third-party, check the documentation to figure out how to make it pay attention to meta tags.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out. I had the global search setup wrong. I seperated it from all the other pages and now the meta tags work.